# GNU recursive make - how to capture make variables to execute nested makefile

Tags: c++, recursion, makefile, gnu-make

I have a bunch of `qmake`-generated makefiles each of which call `make` inside them (recursive `make`) in a chained manner.

After my build is over, the `qmake`-generated makefiles are all on disk so you'd think I could just call `make` on one of them if I wanted to 'replay' one particular makefile. Wrong.

When I try `make`-ing one, it fails, probably because there's a bunch of (environment) variables that it normally inherits from the calling makefile during the normal build.

Except for the variables, each `qmake`-generated makefile is pretty self-contained.

**QUESTION**

How can I simulate the 'normal' environment for a given recursive `make` so that I can call it in isolation?

I'm thinking I'd have to do something with the `--print-data-base` output: parse it and then call `make` with the same vars and values it had during the normal build.

**WHY**

I'm doing this because I need to modify the compile commands for ONE makefile but it's all controlled by the top-level `.conf` and I'm getting in way too deep.

Comment: Can't you just invoke make on the top Makefile and specify the particular goal you are interested in (`make what-i-want`)?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet no because they're chained. Top level make calls Qmake which generates makefile, calls make on that one, calls qmake from inside that one to generate another makefile then calls make on that one.

Comment: @Adrian you do know that Make is not designed for recursivity and the only situation where recursive Make works correctly, is if you call Make on a "black box" submodule, meaning, isolated from the rest of the build, clearly not your case ?

Comment: @MarkGaleck what do mean not designed for recursivity?

Comment: @Adrian if you distribute your Make scripts among subdirectories, use recursive Make invocations on subdirectories whose builds are not isolated, then you cannot have correct behaviour for them.  The correct way to implement distributed makefiles is to use textual include rather than semantic calls. This has been known from the beginning of Make but unfortunately it is not explicitly mentioned in the manual and most engineers who are used to C-type calling paradigm, continue to use it for Make.  See http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf .

Comment: @Adrian One correct way to implement distributed makefiles, not by calling but by inclusion, is described in https://evbergen.home.xs4all.nl/nonrecursive-make.html

Comment: @MarkGaleck why is the behavior incorrect?

Comment: @MarkGaleck I'm using recursive make and it works fine. I get binary equality.

Comment: @Adrian because the Make dependency tree is partitioned into subsets that do not communicate with each other so the partial trees are incomplete.  See the paper.

Comment: @Adrian it is not about binary equality of the results, that is not where the problem lies.  You have to read the paper... at the least the gist of it, is not very complicated.

Comment: @MarkGaleck I know that dependencies cannot be communicated between makes

Comment: @Adrian well, there you have it...you know it already

Comment: @MarkGaleck but that's not my problem and it's not my question. If my question is unclear let me know and I'll clarify.

Comment: @Adrian that's why recursivity by calling, works for "black box" subdirectories - because such a subdirectory, does not to communicate to the parent Make invocation. But if the directory is not isolated, by definition it has to communicate, but it can't.

Comment: @Adrian I am sorry, I was not answering your question...  I was questioning your method... that's why I put it in the comments.  I am sorry if I say things that you are not interested in hearing...

Comment: @MarkGaleck this is about the make "env" variables: when make calls make it passes env variables. When I attempt to execute a make that's in the middle of the chain, it fails because it doesn't get the env vars that it normally gets.

Comment: @Adrian and you are saying, you can make the communication up the chain of recursive invocations, work, by using these env variables?

Comment: @MarkGaleck I don't know. I'm asking if that's the only consideration.

Comment: @Adrian well... let me put it this way, to your question "how can I simulate the normal environment for a given recursive make so that I can call it in isolation", I always thought the answer was "impossible, due to issues shown in the Miller paper".  That's all.

Comment: @MarkGaleck I'll read it and get back to you.

Comment: @Adrian if you think you have it under control and the Miller paper does not apply in your case, then I am sorry for bothering you.  It is always the case of "don't do X unless you know what you are doing", of course.  If you know what you are doing, then...  my comments do not apply and I apologize.

Comment: @MarkGaleck this was written in 1998. Did make even have parallel abilities at that time?

Comment: @Adrian of course...  Make is inherently designed for parallel execution, from the beginning.  '-j' option is implemented precisely in order to disable that capability in case people have faulty makefiles, not to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem is that you need to find this information before you get a chance to make any changes to the generated makefiles.  Therefore, this solution is focused on shell commands (I'm assuming you're on Linux, since you don't say).

After starting your build, the first time, use something like:

```
ps -ef | head -1
ps -ef | grep make
```

to find make processes involved in the build.  The PID column lists the Process ID of the make process, while the PPID column lists that of its parent.  Use this information to find the top-level make process.  Then, run:

```
strings /proc/<pid>/environ | sort > /tmp/make_env
env | sort > /tmp/normal_env
diff /tmp/normal_env /tmp/make_env
```

This will show you how the make process' environment differs from that of your current shell.

Now, that might not solve your problem, because GNU Make allows variables to be specified as commandline parameters.  So, you should also check how it's being run:

```
strings /proc/<pid>/cmdline
```

That will print each commandline argument of <pid>, on a separate line.

BTW, when variables are passed to GNU Make via commandline arguments, they're handled by overriding any instance of the same variable, that might be contained within the makefile.

---

Within a makefile, you can see its environment using:

```
$(info My environment is $(shell env))
```

You can see its commandline options using:

```
$(info MAKEFLAGS = $(MAKEFLAGS))
```

If you *only* want to see the overrides, use MAKEOVERRIDES:

```
$(info MAKEOVERRIDES = $(MAKEOVERRIDES))
```

Finally, the targets can be seen using:

```
$(info MAKECMDGOALS = $(MAKECMDGOALS))
```